# want to join title in url and want to match in another page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

hi i have page in which i am getting post id using get method after that i am matching that data and after that showing the data which is equal to that id

It is working my successfully,  my question is i also want to join title in url from where i am getting id. Kindly help me because my title have some space so how to remove that space and then how i will join that title to check that either this is equal to that id or not.

my code by matching id i am getting  the same data

```
<?php
$var = $_GET['apple.id'];

        $all=$this->db->select('*');
        $join=$this->db->join('choclate AS C', 'apple.id=C.id_fk', 'INNER');
        $get=$this->db->where("apple.id =",$var); 
        $a=$this->db->get('apple');


if($a->num_rows() > 0) { 
    foreach($a->result() as $Result)
     {
?>
```

Comment: after getting the values, just concatenate it

Comment: yea this is my question that how can i concate it?

Comment: I am not clear with your information. Could you elaborate more?